# Struct initialization in if statements

Tags: if-statement, struct, go

I want to check if a struct is empty, i.e. if all of its fields are set to their default value. The following works as expected:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type MyStruct struct {
    field1 string
    field2 int
}

func main() {
    var mine MyStruct
    empty := MyStruct{}

    // Check if mine is empty.
    if mine == empty {
        fmt.Print("mine is empty")
    }
}
```

I wanted to shorten this a bit so I moved the empty struct initialization into the if statement:

```
func main() {
    var mine MyStruct

    // Check if mine is empty.
    if mine == MyStruct{} {
        fmt.Print("mine is empty")
    }
}
```

But that does not work: `syntax error: unexpected }, expecting := or = or comma`. Even the following does not work although it seems almost the same as the first example:

```
func main() {
    var mine MyStruct

    // Check if mine is empty.
    if empty := MyStruct{}; mine == empty {
        fmt.Print("mine is empty")
    }
}
```

The compiler says: `syntax error: need trailing comma before newline in composite literal`. I found the following code to work, however:

```
func main() {
    var mine MyStruct

    // Check if mine is empty.
    if mine == *new(MyStruct) {
        fmt.Print("mine is empty")
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why the two above examples are not accepted by the compiler? And while we're at it: What's the idiomatic way to check for an "empty" struct? The last example works but looks a bit odd to me.

Comment: http://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Resolve the `{}` ambiguity with parentheses. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type MyStruct struct {
    field1 string
    field2 int
}

func main() {
    var mine MyStruct

    // Check if mine is empty.
    if mine == (MyStruct{}) {
        fmt.Print("mine is empty")
    }
}
```

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Composite literals](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals)
>
> A parsing ambiguity arises when a composite literal using the TypeName
>   form of the LiteralType appears as an operand between the keyword and
>   the opening brace of the block of an "if", "for", or "switch"
>   statement, and the composite literal is not enclosed in parentheses,
>   square brackets, or curly braces. In this rare case, the opening brace
>   of the literal is erroneously parsed as the one introducing the block
>   of statements. To resolve the ambiguity, the composite literal must
>   appear within parentheses.